# Почему не подключается @media

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать шаблон для бургер-меню, не понимаю почему не подключается @media

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html.body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}
.header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0469;
}
.header__body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__burger {
  display: none;
}
.header__menu {
  padding: 0;
}
.header__list {
  display: flex;
}
.header__list-style {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.header__logo-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.header__logo {
  flex: 0 0 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header__link {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
}
.content__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header__burger {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .header__burger-span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    top: 9px;
  }
  .header__burger:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .header__burger:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="header__body">
                        <a href="#" class="header__logo">
                            <img src="#" alt="" class="header__logo-img">
                        </a>
                        <div class="header__burger">
                            <span class="header__burger-span"></span>
                        </div>
                        <nav class="header__menu">
                            <ul class="header__list">
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="content__text">
                        <p>
                            reprehenderit beatae ea cumque explicabo tenetur maxime doloribus sit qui. Soluta, vel porro.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           s, cumque quaerat vel unde velit temporibus quisquam iure saepe praesentium! Aut ut reprehenderit beatae ea cumque explicabo tenetur maxime doloribus sit qui. Soluta, vel porro.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Прямо здесь в показанном вами примере всё успешно подключилось. В чём проблема?

Comment: При ширине экрана меньше, чем 768px меню-бургер не появляется, более того медиа запрос в devtools не показан, т.е браузер как будто не видит этот запрос

Comment: я добавил padding: 10px 15px; в класс .header__burger и всё заработало. У вас проблема с псевдоэлементами наверное

Comment: @VictorBej меню-бургер и не должно появляться из-за некорректных стилей, а вот медиа запрос вполне срабатывает и отображается в этом самом devtools (по крайней мере в моём браузере)

Comment: html,body. а у вас html.body

Comment: @VictorBej если хотите есть готовый макет . Могу дать ссылку

Comment: @DjangoStudent если можно, скиньте ссылку

Comment: @VictorBej Добрый день! Уже в ответе

Comment: @VictorBej Ссылка: https://codepen.io/Abdulazis/pen/ExNeGvz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас всё отлично работает. Просто вы поставили на `.header__burger` `width:30px` и `height:20px` но эти коды зачем то не работают. Самый простой способ избежать от проблем это поставить Padding! Я поставил вот так:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}
.header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0469;
}
.header__body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__burger {
  display: none;
}
.header__menu {
  padding: 0;
}
.header__list {
  display: flex;
}
.header__list-style {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.header__logo-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.header__logo {
  flex: 0 0 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header__link {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
}
.content__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header__burger {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 15px /* ////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
  }
  .header__burger-span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    top: 9px;
  }
  .header__burger:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .header__burger:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="header__body">
                        <a href="#" class="header__logo">
                            <img src="#" alt="" class="header__logo-img">
                        </a>
                        <div class="header__burger">
                            <span class="header__burger-span"></span>
                        </div>
                        <nav class="header__menu">
                            <ul class="header__list">
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__list-style">
                                    <a href="" class="header__link">Главная</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="content__text">
                        <p>
                            reprehenderit beatae ea cumque explicabo tenetur maxime doloribus sit qui. Soluta, vel porro.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           s, cumque quaerat vel unde velit temporibus quisquam iure saepe praesentium! Aut ut reprehenderit beatae ea cumque explicabo tenetur maxime doloribus sit qui. Soluta, vel porro.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```